# $V_\lambda$ models

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I have two question about $V_\lambda$ models:

1. I know that, if $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible then
   $$
   V_\kappa\models ZFC
   $$
   But, the converse statement is true? i.e. if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal such that $V_\lambda\models ZFC$, then $\lambda$ must be strongly inaccessible cardinal?
2. is there a limit ordinal $\lambda$ such that $V_\lambda\nvDash(\text{replacement axiom})$?

I think that the first question is not true, but I can't find a counterexample. For the second question I don't have idea.

Can someone help me? Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $(1)$, the answer is **no**; if $V_\kappa\models$ZFC we say $\kappa$ is a [worldly cardinal](http://cantorsattic.info/Worldly), and this is a strictly weaker condition than strong inaccessibility.

In particular, it's easy to see that (under reasonable hypotheses) we can have a singular worldly cardinal. Working in an appropriate model of ZFC, for $\alpha$ an ordinal let $f(\alpha)$ be the least height of a transitive elementary submodel containing $V_\alpha$ as an element. Then $\lambda=\sup\{0, f(0), f(f(0)), ...\}$ is worldly, since $V_\lambda$ is the union of a chain of elementary submodels. However, we have $cof(\lambda)=\omega$, hence $\lambda$ is not inaccessible.

---

For $(2)$, the answer is **yes**: as long as $\lambda$ is "easily seen" to be singular, then $V_\lambda$ won't satisfy Replacement. For example, $V_{\omega^2}$ doesn't satisfy Replacement since the map $$\omega\rightarrow\omega^2: n\mapsto \omega\cdot n$$ is definable inside $V_{\omega^2}$.

(Note that since Replacement is a scheme rather than a single axiom, there could be some interesting distinctions to be made in terms of how *much* Replacement a given level of the cumulative hierarchy - or indeed any "reasonable" transitive set - satisfies. If you're interested in this sort of thing you might like thinking about [admissible sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory).)

Comment: For (1) I think it is better to argue directly that the first wordly cardinal, if it exists, is of cofinality $\omega$. Maybe that is what you meant, but the mention of "under reasonable hypotheses" makes it look as if there is something subtle going on.